# How do I define default attribute property values in Moose?

Tags: perl, moose

As the title suggests, I'd like to be able to do something like this in my class:

```
use MooseX::Declare;

class MyClass {
    default_attribute_propeties(
        is       => 'ro',
        lazy     => 1,
        required => 1,
    );

    has [qw( some standard props )] => ();

    has 'override_default_props' => (
        is       => 'rw',
        required => 0,
        ...
    );

    ...
}
```

That is, define some default property values that will apply to all attribute definitions unless overridden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to write some custom attribute declarations, that provide some default options.  This is covered in [Moose::Cookbook::Extending::Recipe1](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Cookbook/Extending/Recipe1.pod), e.g.:

```
package MyApp::Mooseish;

use Moose ();
use Moose::Exporter;

Moose::Exporter->setup_import_methods(
    install     => [ qw(import unimport init_meta) ],
    with_meta   => ['has_table'],
    also        => 'Moose',
);

sub has_table
{
    my ($meta, $name, %config) = @_;

    $meta->add_attribute(
        $name,

        # overridable defaults.
        is => 'rw',
        isa => 'Value', # any defined non-reference; hopefully the caller
                        # passed their own type, which will override
                        # this one.
        # other options you may wish to supply, or calculate based on
        # other arguments passed to this function...

        %config,
    );
}
```

And then in your class:

```
package MyApp::SomeObject;

use MyApp::Moosish;

has_table => (
    # any normal 'has' options;
    # will override the defaults.
);

# remaining class definition as normal.
```

Comment: For clarification, I take it that `$name` in the `has_table` function is given using `has_table 'my_attr' => ( ... )`? Also, do you mean `...->build_import_methods` instead of `...->setup_import_methods`?

Comment: @gvkv: That's correct - has_table is just a regular function, where the first argument is the attribute name and the remaining arguments are the attribution option fields and values.  <CR>  I mean setup_import_methods -- build_import_methods returns the coderefs which allows you to modify them, but then you must install them yourself -- this is not necessary for such a simple case.